# Get Device time in UTC format regardless time zone

Tags: java, android, datetime, timezone, utc

How i can get the local time of the device and convert it to global UTC format for my country ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you want to do, but if you want the date and time in normal format you can do it this way:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
String dateAndTime = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
```

String dateAndTime will be something like `2012/01/01 11:13`, according to the date & time the device was set to, so it shows the same time as the device's clock.
You can play around with the format a little bit by changing `"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm"` to whatever you like.

Hope this helps!

UPDATE:
To get the UTC time do it this way:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm");
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
String dateAndTimeUTC = dateFormat.format(new Date());
```

Comment: Except that will be in the local time zone, not UTC.

Comment: Yeah, but `user1812264` asks for the time in his country.

Comment: Well, he asked for "global UTC format for my country" - it's not clear, but given the title, I don't believe he actually wants local time.

Comment: Thank you all for your feedbacks but the case as below :
i need to make a HTTP request with UTC time regardless my current time and time zone since the server deals with UTC time for all requests .

Comment: @UBA_MobileTeam In that case, you can do it with `.setTimeZone()`. See the updated answer

Answer (score 5):

Don't get the *local* time at all - just get the UTC value to start with, e.g.

```
long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Or:

```
Date date = new Date();
```

If you need to format this as a string, use `SimpleDateFormat` but remember to set the time zone appropriately. For example:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
                                               Locale.US);
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/Utc"));
String text = format.format(new Date());
```

(It's not clear what you mean by "global UTC format for my country" - UTC simply *is* global, and it's not a *format*, it's a time zone.)

Comment: It's not clear who that will return to me the UTC time for my country,the result of the below code returns the current time without consider the time zone :

        long dateInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
 String format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
 final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        String dateString = sdf.format(new Date(dateInMillis));

Comment: @user1812264: There's no such thing as "the UTC time for my country" - UTC is global.

Comment: @user1812264: Just `new Date()` will give the current time in UTC, but yo haven't set the time zone in your `SimpleDateFormat`, so it's defaulting to the local one. You've got to explicitly set it to UTC. `Date` itself isn't aware of time zone.

Comment: erm thought I was an expert on time zones and I always thought GMT is a time zone, not UTC? The only thing that makes me insecure of what I otherwise considered was The Truth is that Jon Skeet with more than half a million credits on Stackoverflow says something else! But seriously, please clarify Jon Skeet.

Comment: @MartinAndersson: Well, the time zone London observes is normally known as "Europe/London", which varies between GMT and BST. UTC is usually regarded as a time zone in its own right. GMT is always UTC+0 (as far as I'm aware), but it wouldn't be appropriate to talk about being in a time zone of "GMT" in my view. UTC is a much more reasonable approach... it's less UK-centric, to start with.

Answer (score 2):

Existing answers are correct and they provided the right direction in Nov 2012 (when the question was asked). In March 2014, the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html) was released as part of the **Java 8 standard library** which supplanted the error-prone `java.util` date-time API and their corresponding parsing/formatting type, `SimpleDateFormat`, and since then it has been strongly recommended to switch to `java.time`, the modern date-time API.

### Solution using `java.time`:

You can simply use [`Instant#now`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#now--) to get the current moment independent of the timezone (i.e. at UTC). Note that the `java.time` API is based on [ISO 8601 standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

In case, you need the current date-time in a specific timezone, you can use [`ZonedDateTime#now(ZoneId)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#now-java.time.ZoneId-), which you can also format in a desired format.

**Demo:**

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Current moment
        System.out.println(Instant.now());

        // Current date-time in a specific timezone e.g. America/New_York
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
        System.out.println(zdt);

        // Output in a custom format e.g. EEE MMM dd, uuuu 'at' hh:mm:ss a
        String formattedStr = zdt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd, uuuu 'at' hh:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH));
        System.out.println(formattedStr);
    }
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/yu1ZIE)

**Note:** [Never use a `DateTimeFormatter` for custom formats, and a `SimpleDateFormat` without a `Locale`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573).

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.